# Why server load is significant when CPU IO and memory are only lightly use

Tags: top

I have a very powerful server.

32 core and 64G memory with SSD

Here is the result of iostat -xk 5

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          13.43    0.00    8.68    1.74    0.00   76.15

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.77     0.00    0.50    0.00     1.97     0.00     7.94     0.00    0.10   0.10   0.00
sdb            1487.51   562.92 3596.86  299.21 21888.08  3448.81    13.01     9.94    2.55   0.10  40.26
sdd               5.03    57.98   65.03   86.51   679.05   578.13    16.59     0.28    1.82   0.12   1.80
sdc               2.21     0.00    0.82    0.00    12.24     0.00    29.67     0.00    0.27   0.25   0.02

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          12.98    0.00    8.46    0.41    0.00   78.15

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb              35.80   377.40  656.80  237.00  3714.40  2457.60    13.81     1.34    1.50   0.17  14.96
sdd               0.00   106.20    2.00  143.80     8.00  1000.80    13.84     0.43    2.96   0.12   1.80
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          10.96    0.00    7.11    0.16    0.00   81.78

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb              10.60   190.60  429.80  220.40  2637.60  1644.00    13.17     0.50    0.76   0.12   7.94
sdd               0.00    58.40   17.80   69.80   345.60   512.80    19.60     0.23    2.65   0.12   1.04
sdc               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

and top

```
root@host [/]# top
top - 18:20:27 up 15 min,  1 user,  load average: 4.81, 5.63, 3.90
Tasks: 802 total,   3 running, 786 sleeping,   0 stopped,  13 zombie
Cpu(s): 13.4%us,  8.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 76.2%id,  1.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  15981924k total,  1705512k used, 14276412k free,   457408k buffers
Swap:  4194296k total,        0k used,  4194296k free,   455800k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
14351 investgr  20   0     0    0    0 Z 28.3  0.0   0:00.15 php <defunct>
14377 sexsmovi  20   0     0    0    0 Z 24.5  0.0   0:00.13 php <defunct>
14359 hearsttr  20   0     0    0    0 Z 20.7  0.0   0:00.11 php <defunct>
14348 sexsmovi  20   0     0    0    0 Z 18.8  0.0   0:00.10 php <defunct>
14350 sexsmovi  20   0 35420  11m 4668 S 17.0  0.1   0:00.09 php
14362 cuntschi  20   0     0    0    0 Z 17.0  0.0   0:00.09 php <defunct>
14367 investgr  20   0     0    0    0 Z 15.1  0.0   0:00.08 php <defunct>
14366 investgr  20   0 33568 9064 4472 S 13.2  0.1   0:00.07 php
14372 investgr  20   0 33568 8904 4420 S 13.2  0.1   0:00.07 php
14373 investgr  20   0 33568 9028 4456 S 13.2  0.1   0:00.07 php
14376 hearsttr  20   0     0    0    0 Z 11.3  0.0   0:00.06 php <defunct>
14336 hearsttr  20   0 34656  10m 4684 S  9.4  0.1   0:00.11 php
14340 root      20   0  3096 1444  760 R  5.7  0.0   0:00.05 top
14388 sexsmovi  20   0 30720 5996 3896 R  5.7  0.0   0:00.03 php
 1161 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  1.9  0.0   0:00.40 flush-8:48
 1959 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  1.9  0.0   0:01.22 kondemand/1
 5546 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1568 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.25 httpd
 5842 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1544 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.26 httpd
 5843 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1544 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.23 httpd
 6012 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1568 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.32 httpd
 6041 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1536 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.19 httpd
 9143 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1556 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.26 httpd
 9158 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1536 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.17 httpd
11916 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1552 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.07 httpd
12508 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1504 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.03 httpd
12523 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1504 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.04 httpd
14051 investgr  20   0 33568 9360 4612 S  1.9  0.1   0:00.08 php
14076 investgr  20   0 33568 9328 4640 S  1.9  0.1   0:00.08 php
14306 hearsttr  20   0 34392  10m 4636 S  1.9  0.1   0:00.09 php
16554 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1572 S  1.9  0.5   0:01.11 httpd
20263 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1584 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.99 httpd
26535 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1576 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.64 httpd
26738 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1584 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.67 httpd
26740 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1580 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.68 httpd
26963 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1572 S  1.9  0.5   0:00.78 httpd
30587 nobody    20   0  153m  78m 1568 S  1.9  0.5   0:01.78 httpd
    1 root      20   0  2900 1436 1212 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.99 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.39 migration/0
```

Comment: So CPU usage is only 13%. A lot of Idle CPU. Memory and io is not bottle neck either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CPU is not that loaded. It's only showing ~13%. Your HDD (/dev/sdb) is slightly busy:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdb              35.80   377.40  656.80  237.00  3714.40  2457.60    13.81     1.34    1.50   0.17  14.96
```

The load reported in top @ ~4.81 just means that there are an average of ~4 processes in a ready to run state and are waiting for system resources to become available so that they can run.

The "defunct" processes are most likely your issue, they're probably blocking on some resource for all the other processes.